# Clausulas e mensagem JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

Preciso que quando `$DsTpVeiculo` for Cavalo Truck o `input` seja preenchido e mostre uma mensagem pedindo para preencher, e se for Truck ou Bitruck não deverá ser preenchido mostrando uma mensagem também. Alguma mensagem em JS.

***Código:***

```
<?php  
   if($DsTpVeiculo == 'Cavalo Truck'){ ?>
    <td><input type="text" id="carreta" name="NrPlacaCarreta" value="<?php echo $NrPlacaCarreta; ?>"/></td>
<?php 
   }elseif($DsTpVeiculo == 'Bitruck' || $DsTpVeiculo == 'Truck'){ ?>
    <td><input type="text" id="carreta" name="NrPlacaCarreta" value="<?php echo $NrPlacaCarreta; ?>"/></td>
<?php
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando for truck ou bitruck, desabilita o input usando   a mensagem você pode usar o alert(), mais ou menos assim.

```
if($DsTpVeiculo == 'Bitruck' || $DsTpVeiculo == 'Truck'){ 

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Mensagem!");</script>';
?>
    <td><input disabled="true" type="text" id="carreta" name="NrPlacaCarreta" value="<?php echo $NrPlacaCarreta; ?>"/></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver o seu problema assim:

```
    <?php  
        $DsTpVeiculo = "Cavalo Truck";

        if($DsTpVeiculo == 'Cavalo Truck'){ 
            $NrPlacaCarreta = "Meu preenchimento de input;";
    ?>
    <td><input type="text" id="carreta" name="NrPlacaCarreta" value="<?php echo $NrPlacaCarreta; ?>"/></td>
    <?php 
       }elseif($DsTpVeiculo == 'Bitruck' || $DsTpVeiculo == 'Truck'){ 
            $NrPlacaCarreta = "";
    ?>
        <td><input type="text" id="carreta" name="NrPlacaCarreta" value="<?php echo $NrPlacaCarreta; ?>"/></td>
    <?php
       }
    ?>
    <script>
        var DsTpVeiculo = "<?php echo $DsTpVeiculo; ?>";
        if(DsTpVeiculo == "Cavalo Truck"){
            alert("Minha mensagem Cavalo Truck");
        }else if(DsTpVeiculo == "Bitruck" || DsTpVeiculo == "Truck"){
            alert("Minha mensagem Bitruck ou Truck");
        }
    </script>
```